# Responsive Bootstrap Menu Not Working (Bootstrap & HTML)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design

For some reason once I collapse my navbar, everything seems to look fine but when I press on the open menu button the menu doesn't seem to appear. All it does is just flash white and then flashes back to red again. How can fix this?

Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <title>Propel WD</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Users/Ryan/Downloads/LAPTOP3.JPG">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
 integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <style>
   .opacityChange {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s linear 0s 1 alternate;
  animation: myfirst 1s linear 0s 1 alternate;
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {opacity: 0.0;}
  25%  {opacity: 0.25;}
  50%  {opacity: 0.5;}
  75%  {opacity: 0.75;}
  100% {opacity: 1.0;}
   }

   @keyframes myfirst {
     0%   {opacity: 0.0;}
  25%  {opacity: 0.25;}
  50%  {opacity: 0.5;}
  75%  {opacity: 0.75;}
  100% {opacity: 1.0;}
   }
   
   hr {
     height: 0.1px;
     background-color: gainsboro;
   }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60" class="text-center" style="margin: 40px; font-family: Lato;" data-toggle="navbar-collapse">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #F44336; border-bottom: none;">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header" style="color: white;">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage"><div style="color: white; font-size: 16px;">Propel WD <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span></div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="file://localhost/Applications/propelOMS%3EHome.html"><div style="color: white; font-size: 13px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></div></a></li>
   <li><a href="file://localhost/Applications/propelOMS%3EAbout.html"><div style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">ABOUT</div></a></li>
   <li><a href="file://localhost/Applications/propelOMS%3EServices.html"><div style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">SERVICES</div></a></li>
   <li><a href="file://localhost/Applications/propelOMS%3EPricing.html"><div style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">PRICING</div></a></li>
   <li><a href="file://localhost/Applications/propelOMS%3EOI.html"><div style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">QUESTIONS</div></a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#"><div style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">CONTACT</div></a></li>
   <li><a href="file://localhost/Applications/propelOMS%3ETC.html" onclick="window.open('file://localhost/Applications/propelOMS%3ETC.html', 'newwindow', 'width=400, height='); return false;"><div style="color: white; font-size: 13px;">TERMS</div></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   </div>
 </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to place jQuery before BootstrapJS before anything. [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already have done.

Comment: You have **bootstrapCSS**, then **bootstrapJS**,  a **google font**, then **jQuery** inside your head tag. Unless the code you've posted is not accurate, you haven't.